# RCL circuit sum

Tags: capacitor, inductor, resistance, impedance, series

[image]
Just need help in the daigram of this sum. Can't understand the daigram.will a common resistance be shared between capacitor and inductor or is there 2 resistor and 1 capacitor and inductor with resistance connected with each

Comment: https://tinyurl.com/yj27hqy4  not correct values

Comment: Since the voltages are measured separately across the inductor and capacitor (100 V, 125 V), total of three resistors would need to be modeled it seems.

Answer (score 1):

Well, according to the description we have:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvLYWe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: R1 should go between L & C to avoid Vi getting in the middle to question

Comment: Sir the voltage across resistance which is given as 150v is seperate resisitor and not the resisitor part of L or C right?